# jersey-spring version with spring 4.2.5

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I am upgrading Spring version from 3.0.5 to 4.2.5, currently it uses jersey-spring version 1.3. Up to what version I can upgrade the jersey so that it will be compatible with Spring 4.2.5.

PS: group-id is com.sun.jersey.contribs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to update it to any 1.x version. Spring can be integrated with both 1.x and 2.x, but jersey 2.x is has no backward compatibility with jersey 1.x.

Comment: So, if I move to jersey 2.x, do I need to change all the code that is specific to jersey 1.x?

Comment: That is correct. Jersey 2 is in a completely different package, methods has been removed, and other jersey dependencies have been changed aswell.

Comment: can you suggest what kind of changes should I made to get the most out of jersey 1.9.x after this upgrade?

Comment: I have not worked with jersey 1.x myself, so sadly i cannot make any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade it up to any version, it will work fine.